# SOLR, Error waiting for SolrCore to be loaded on startup

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I tried to test the filter: HunspellStemFilterFactory.

Settings in schema.xml:

```xml
<filter class="solr.HunspellStemFilterFactory" 
    dictionary="sk_SK.dic" 
    affix="sk_SK.aff" 
    ignoreCase="true" 
    strictAffixParsing="false"/>
```

...

I added files: sk_SK.dic and sk_SK.aff to directory(for the affected core):  configsets\default\conf\
There are also files: schema.xml, solrconfig.xml in this location

I use the SolrCloud solution, and after adding this filter and restarting, the core does not load. If i remove the filter from the analyzer configuration in schema.xml, the core is loaded and it's OK

Can you please advise me how to solve this problem?

Thank you,

Best Regards
Patrik

I tried to include the filter in the configuration and expected a change in the functionality of the analyzer

Comment: I will also add information: if I try this configuration locally on Solr (running in standalone mode), it works OK

Comment: Could you share the logs at startup? Any error in Solr Admin when the core fails to load?